# Grant notification access via ADB

Tags: android, shell, automation, adb, android-go

I use a **nokia 2.1** and it currently runs Android 9 (Go Edition). Unfortunately I cannot grant an app notification access via the settings UI. After making much investigation, I found out that some settings have been disabled thanks to the low ram usage flag being set to `True` somewhere in the source code for Android (Go Edition).

My only option right now (apart from rooting) is to grant a particular app [Lawnchair launcher](https://github.com/LawnchairLauncher/Lawnchair)

notification access. The app needs notification access so that it would be able to read notifications (via the notification dots or `NotificationListenerService`) and print them on the "At A Glance" section of the home screen.

Please if it's still possible as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355417/android-notifications-through-adb), I would love to be able to grant this app notification access via ADB. Thanks.

Comment: Out of luck, from what I understand: https://support.google.com/wearos/thread/3175783?hl=en

Comment: have you tried `adb shell pm grant com.name.app android.permission. BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` ?

Comment: doesn't work @Blundell